# Grails Response Map in Integration Tests

Tags: grails, integration-testing, response

I want to get the response map in an integration testing. I have the following code:

```
def myController = new MyController()
myController.params.firstParam = "test"

myController.request.method = "GET"
myController.myAction()
```

Now i want to get the response map of the action, but in the documentation no method is shown to do that...

Greetings

Answer (score 1):

The result of the action is stored within the `modelAndView` property of the controller.

Yor could access the model like this:

```
def yourModel = myController.modelAndView.model
```

It is described in the [Integration Testing](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/guide/single.html#integrationTesting) section of the docs.